# I need help constructing an algorithm to display certain types of content

Tags: arrays, list, algorithm, sorting, arraylist

I have (2) types of content that can appear on a page.

1. "Related Content" = R
2. Copy = C

--

The number of R and C is variable per page.  So you could have the following conditions:
R = 10
C = 3

R = 2
C = 12

R = 4
C = 5

etc, etc

The normal case though, will probably be:
R = (3 --> 7)
C = (5 --> 8)

I would assume that 90% of the time it will fall into that range

--

I am trying to write an algorithm to order the way the content is presented on a page to achieve a balance between (R) and (C).

Rules:

1. a unit of (C) must ALWAYS appear first.
2. Try to avoid ending on a (C)
3. For lists that cannot be evenly divided, put the extra "weight" in the middle

Some examples of what the ideal distribution of content would be:

Case 1:  (R=2, C=8)
Result:
C,C,C,R,C,C,C,R,C,C

Case 2: (C=6, R=4)
Result:
C,R,C,R,C,C,R,C,R,C

Case 3: (C=2. R=6)
Result:
C,R,R,R,C,R,R,R

### This is generally the distribution I want to achieve

I'm having difficulty constructing an algorithm or other method to sort this correctly based on my rules and desired outcomes.  I "know it when I see it", but I'm finding it difficult to convert this into a math equation.  Hopefully someone can give me some pointers

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this as an integer line-drawing problem: you want as strait a line as possible going from `(0,0)` to `(R,C)`; instead of making a choice between `x` and `y`, we are making a choice between `r` and `c`. [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) is an integer-only way to draw the exact line, perfect for your interpolation. There are only two cases, `R` or `C` greater. Instead of setting your initial `y` to be balanced, set it all the way to one side (it depends the mapping of `r` and `c` to `x` and `y`); this will make `C` always be first. You may tweak it a bit with depending on the how undesirable `C` is to have at the end, but if there are not more `C` than `R`, we have naturally `R` at the end.